# How to implement SSO with moodle and wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, moodle

I have moodle installation and wordpress blog. When user logged on to moodle want to access wordpress blog. i want to implement sso with moodle(1.9.7) and wordpress(3.0.1) blog.

I am using [External DB authentication](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/external-database-authentication/) plugin.

I want to access my wordpress blog through my Moodle database. I did all given steps at [Authenticate Users From Moodle Into WordPress MU](http://jasontbedell.com/how-to-authenticate-users-from-moodle-into-wordpress-mu). Right now, admin is able to sign in both moodle and wordpress using my moodle database, But other users in facing "wrong user name or password error".

Kindly advice

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login because you changed you admin password to match on each system.
Your other users can't login because they are in effect using 2 separate accounts.
Your users on Moodle will need their authentication changing in their profile to "External Database", at present they are most likely set to "manual".

Try editing a user profile and change the authentication method to "External Database" then  get the user to login using their Wordpress login details.
Should fix it.
If it works, change all the other accounts to the same setting.
Regards,
Lewis

Comment: This answer does not solves the question subject. Being able to share the same password between two systems does not assure that SSO is possible. SSO states about once logged on a system, a user does not need to log on again on the second system.